# How to get the line number based on substring in codemirror?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I need to get the line number of specific string in the textarea which has codemirror plugin.

```
var editor= CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("refstyle");  

var doc = editor.getDoc();
var cursor = doc.getCursor(); // gets the line number in the cursor position
var line = doc.getLine(cursor.line); // get the line contents 
editor.getSelection(line number)   //it will select the text based on line number
```

So, How can I get the line number based on string (I expect something like doc.getLine(string) or doc.getSelection(String))

Is there any function to get the line number based on the string or to get searched string selected based on line number in the textarea? Pls help!

Comment: please have a look at `http://codemirror.net/demo/search.html` you need to add additonal addon js file for searching function

Answer (score 4):

To search inside a CodeMirror instance, use the [`searchcursor`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addon_searchcursor) addon. It'll give you the line/char position of matches.

Comment: I think this is a valid answer. @Vidhya Raju. Welcome to Stack Overflow! Kindly tick this answer if you have got your solution. Thanks :)

Comment: example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54957259/codemirror-search-and-highlight-multipule-words-without-dialog