# codemirror: search and highlight multipule words without dialog

Tags: javascript, codemirror

**Objective:**
I am using [codemirror](https://codemirror.net/demo/search.html) as editor. I want to

1. Search and highlight multiple strings
2. I want to be able to iterate each number of matches found and print its line number.
3. I want to do it programatically and do no want to use dialog as in example https://codemirror.net/demo/search.html

**Issue:**

1. during while loop only last match is selected, previous ones are cleared , but i also want it hightlighted yellow like https://codemirror.net/demo/search.html

**JSFIDDLE:**  https://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/p7xg1utn/30/

**CODE:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
    mode: "text/html",
    lineNumbers: true,
  });
  //
  function search(val) {
    var cursor = editor.getSearchCursor(val);
    while (cursor.findNext()) {
      editor.setSelection(cursor.from(), cursor.to());
        console.log('found at line ', cursor.pos.from.line + 1);
    }
  }
  //
  $('#search').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    search(/^alpha|^beta/);
  });

  //
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling `setSelection` can only highlight one continuous substring at a time. Instead, you can use the [markText](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#markText) method for this, passing in `cursor.from()` and `cursor.to()` to get the locations you want to highlight:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
    mode: "text/html",
    lineNumbers: true,
  });
  function search(val) {
    var cursor = editor.getSearchCursor(val);
    while (cursor.findNext()) {
        editor.markText(
          cursor.from(),
          cursor.to(),
          { className: 'highlight' }
        );
    }
  }
  //
  $('#search').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    search(/^alpha|^beta/);
  });
});
```

```css
.CodeMirror {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
}
.highlight {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.44.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.44.0/addon/search/searchcursor.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.44.0/codemirror.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <p><strong>Objective:</strong></p>
  <p>Find/search and highlight both words <strong>alpha</strong> and <strong>beta</strong> in codemirror editor</p>
  <button id="search" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Search and highlight</button>
  <br><br>
  <textarea id="code" name="code" rows="8">Text line
alpha 1
Text line
Text line
alpha 2
Text line
Text line
beta 1
Text line</textarea>
```

Comment: unrealted question but how can i know how many matches were found ?  is there an array i can iterate ? Like i search for a string and i want to know x numebr of matches found etc

Comment: Just increment a counter that starts at 0 inside the `while` loop.